# How to modify only the Client ID in an MQTT CONNECT message?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am playing around with MQTT CONNECT messages. I have a simple C program which opens a TCP/IP socket towards an Mosquitto broker running on my laptop, sends an MQTT CONNECT message, (normally) receives the 4 byte long CONNACK reply then closes the socket and exits the program.

Currently I do not build my own CONNECT message but use one from a Wireshark capture.

[image: Wireshark Capture Screenshot]

It can be exported as a C array, the MQTT part:

```c
char packet_bytes[] = {
  0x10, 0x20, 0x00, 0x06, 0x4d, 0x51, 0x49, 0x73,
  0x64, 0x70, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x00, 0x12,
  0x72, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x34, 0x38,
  0x35, 0x38, 0x39, 0x30, 0x38, 0x35, 0x37, 0x31,
  0x39, 0x34
};
```

Using this unmodified array everything works just fine, here is the broker's output:

```bash
1486237905: New connection from 192.168.1.2 on port 1883.
1486237905: New client connected from 192.168.1.2 as root.1485890857194 (c1, k60).
1486237905: Sending CONNACK to root.1485890857194 (0, 0)
1486237905: Socket error on client root.1485890857194, disconnecting.
```

---

The problems start when I want to modify the Client ID in the message. My simplest attempt is chopping the last character `4` from the end of the ID.

I think this requires three modifications in the actual code.

1. Deleting the last byte from the array, the `0x34`.
2. Decrementing the the `Remaining Length` field (2nd byte in the array) in the message. So from 32 to 31, `0x20` --> `0x1F`.
3. Decrementing the number of bytes parameter of the `send` function. From 34 to 33. (+2 because of the `Header Flags` and `Remaining Length` fields)

---

```c
char packet_bytes[] = {
  0x10, 0x1F, 0x00, 0x06, 0x4d, 0x51, 0x49, 0x73,
  0x64, 0x70, 0x03, 0x02, 0x00, 0x3c, 0x00, 0x12,
  0x72, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x74, 0x2e, 0x31, 0x34, 0x38,
  0x35, 0x38, 0x39, 0x30, 0x38, 0x35, 0x37, 0x31,
  0x39
};


if( send(s , packet_bytes , 33, 0) < 0)
{
    puts("Send failed");
    return 1;
}
```

It does not work, here is the broker's output:

```bash
1486239491: New connection from 192.168.1.2 on port 1883.
1486239491: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

---

I know that the `Remaining Length` field requires special enconding but not under 128.

[image: Remaining Length Table]

What did I miss here, what should I modify beside the `Remaining Length` field?

Comment: Does the broker not log the socket error code or anything like that?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Actually I did not check as I thought  a verbose console logging will do. I will check it, I have to find log files under windows.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Actually I was so busy in finding the mistake at client side, I have not thought of searching more detailed server logs so thanks for pointing out. I will update if I find somethin.

Comment: Currently I have no [additional logs](http://iot.stackexchange.com/q/956/14) available.

Comment: Just to confirm: there is no "Send failed" error; it's all on the broker? I wonder if it'd help if you used Wireshark for the version when you get the error, to see if the packet is malformed or something?

Comment: @Aurora0001 No, the data is sent, only in this case I do not receive CONACK, the recv function returns 0 and the program exits. I will try to do a capture then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find my mistake. Mistakenly I assumed that the Client ID is a fix field but it is only part of the Payload of the message thus a **length-prefix** is needed. From the [specifications](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718028):

> The payload of the CONNECT Packet contains one or more length-prefixed
>   fields, whose presence is determined by the flags in the variable
>   header. These fields, if present, MUST appear in the order Client
>   Identifier, Will Topic, Will Message, User Name, Password

So one more byte should be decremented in the message. The correct steps:

1. Deleting the last byte from the array, the 0x34.
2. Decrementing the the Remaining Length field (2nd byte in the array) in the message. So from 32 to 31, 0x20 --> 0x1F.
3. **Decrementing the length-prefix byte of the Client ID in the payload. In my case it is the 16th byte (counting from 1) `0x12` ---> `0x11`.**
4. Decrementing the number of bytes parameter of the send function. From 34 to 33. (+2 because of the Header Flags and Remaining Length fields)

After this additional step the broker sent back the CONNACK message.