# How to enable detailed logging of Mosquitto broker on Windows 7?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, microsoft-windows

I have a previous [question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/955/14) and to get closer to a solution I want to enable Mosquitto broker logging on Windows 7.

Originally I have started the broker manually as follows:

```bash
mosquitto -p 1883 -v
```

`-v` means verbose console logging. But this does not provide enough information, only the following line in case of my problem:

```bash
1486293976: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

---

I have tried doing what is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13986313/3820025). Here is the config file's logging part:

```bash
# Note that if the broker is running as a Windows service it will default to
# "log_dest none" and neither stdout nor stderr logging is available.
# Use "log_dest none" if you wish to disable logging.
log_dest stdout

# If using syslog logging (not on Windows), messages will be logged to the
# "daemon" facility by default. Use the log_facility option to choose which of
# local0 to local7 to log to instead. The option value should be an integer
# value, e.g. "log_facility 5" to use local5.
#log_facility

# Types of messages to log. Use multiple log_type lines for logging
# multiple types of messages.
# Possible types are: debug, error, warning, notice, information, 
# none, subscribe, unsubscribe, websockets, all.
# Note that debug type messages are for decoding the incoming/outgoing
# network packets. They are not logged in "topics".
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information

# Change the websockets logging level. This is a global option, it is not
# possible to set per listener. This is an integer that is interpreted by
# libwebsockets as a bit mask for its lws_log_levels enum. See the
# libwebsockets documentation for more details. "log_type websockets" must also
# be enabled.
#websockets_log_level 0

# If set to true, client connection and disconnection messages will be included
# in the log.
connection_messages true

# If set to true, add a timestamp value to each log message.
log_timestamp true
```

In this case I have started the broker as follows:

```bash
mosquitto -p 1883
```

`-v` option would override the config file with the default config so I have left that out. But I see no logging on the console.

---

Instead of `stdout` I have tried to log into a file, and changed the configuration as follows:

```bash
log_dest file d:\mosquitto.txt
```

I have created the file manually and started the broker in the same way but no avail.

---

I do not get any log message if I do not use the `-v` option.
How should it be done properly?

Comment: Does `log_type debug` or `log_type all` give you any more information?

Comment: @Aurora0001 No matter what I set in the configuration file, I get no logging output. Only the `-v` option gives some log entries on the console (cmd) but that uses default config.

Comment: @JimmyWestberg While your answer gives a convenient logging mechanism, it only logs topic related information while I originally was interested in the mosquitto broker's error/warning logs which I tired to configure in the mosquitto config file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [answer](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/1208/14) of this question: [How to enable WebSockets on Mosquitto running on Windows?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1205/how-to-enable-websockets-on-mosquitto-running-on-windows) actually answered this question as well.

As it turned out the Mosquitto's config file has to be added explicitly in the command line.

> When you run mosquitto from the command line you have to explicitly
> point to the config file with the -c option
>
> ```
> mosquitto -v -c /path/to/mosquitto.conf
> ```

After this I was able to obtain additional information about socket error events or such.

> 1489438223: mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date 24/08/2016
> 21:03:24.73) starting
>
> 1489438223: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
>
> 1489438223: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
>
> **1489438223: Error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network**
> **address/port) is normally permitted.**
>
> 1489438341: mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date 24/08/2016 21:03:24.73) starting
>
> 1489438341: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
>
> 1489438341: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
>
> 1489438341: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
>
> 1489438363: New connection from 192.168.1.4 on port 1883.
>
> 1489438363: New client connected from 192.168.1.4 as root.1489438369381 (c1, k60, u'phone').
>
> 1489438363: Sending CONNACK to root.1489438369381 (0, 0)
>
> 1489438363: Received SUBSCRIBE from root.1489438369381
>
> 1489438363:   room/humidity (QoS 1)
>
> 1489438363: root.1489438369381 1 room/humidity
>
> 1489438363: Sending > SUBACK to root.1489438369381
>
> **1489438453: Client root.1489438369381 has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.**
>
> **1489438453: Socket error on client root.1489438369381, disconnecting.**

Answer (score 8):

This is what I do. Following script saved as timestampLog.vbs:

```
Dim str
Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
  str = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "[" & now & "]" & str
Loop
```

Then I run this from command line:

```
C:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto_sub -t +/# -v | cscript //nologo timestampLog.vbs 2> C:\*USER*\Desktop\logfile.txt
```

Where as you might want to change path to your mosquitto folder and change the "logfile.txt" path to whatever you want.

If this is what you are looking for I don't know but someone else might like the solution provided here. To break the command line down:

`C:\Program Files\mosquitto>` is the local folder for Mosquitto

`mosquitto_sub` is the .exe file used to listen to the broker

`-t +/#` "-t" is to give the .exe file the information to listen to **t**opic of **+/#** which is all topics from clients. "#" would mean all topics, even broker created topics. **\$SYS/#** will only listen to broker topics. It is possible to have multiple -t (I think).

`-v` is to give the .exe file the information to output the topics verbose, i.e. also output the topic itself (not only it's value).

`|` is to pipe this first command into the script command.

`cscript //nologo timestampLog.vbs` is to execute cscript.exe with the vbs script that we previously wrote.  `//nologo` is telling the command line prompt to output the cscript.exe output information into a external file instead of the prompt itself.

`2>` is telling the command line prompt to output "StdErr" (which is what we told the script to funnel all messages to in the .vbs file).

`C:\*USER*\Desktop\logfile.txt` is the path and file name of the output. Instead of .txt you might consider using .log or something else.

Answer (score 4):

1. log payload

   If you want to log the PUBLISH message payload, 
   here I add custome log in mosquitto v1.5.3 souce:

   [Source on Git Hub](https://github.com/yurenchen000/mosquitto/commit/a33955626079d83aee0745418c954369cf12fffa).

   //only show ASCII payload, binary data maybe broke the terminal.
2. usage
   in mosquitto.conf:

   log_type payload
3. result

   log become:

   ```
   1542293777: Received PUBLISH from client_20454 (d0, q0, r0, m0, '$rpc/device1/client_20454/25MhY4xUwiMZIuytfb89Vjrh4QU=/req', ... (64 bytes))
   1542293777: > payload: '{"method":"ServerExposed.Ping","params":[{"Num":20454}],"id":0}'
   1542293777: Sending PUBLISH to device1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, '$rpc/device1/client_20454/25MhY4xUwiMZIuytfb89Vjrh4QU=/req', ... (64 bytes))

   1542293777: Received PUBLISH from device1 (d0, q0, r0, m0, '$rpc/device1/client_20454/25MhY4xUwiMZIuytfb89Vjrh4QU=/res', ... (57 bytes))
   1542293777: > payload: '{"id":0,"result":{"Done":true,"Num":20454},"error":null}'
   1542293777: Sending PUBLISH to client_20454 (d0, q0, r0, m0, '$rpc/device1/client_20454/25MhY4xUwiMZIuytfb89Vjrh4QU=/res', ... (57 bytes))
   ```

Comment: What happens when you publish a binary payload?

Comment: oh, only tested with ascii payload, binary maybe broke the terminal, forgot to say

Answer (score 2):

I found this a while back but I'm unable to attribute to the original author.  Works great for existing logs, but can't 'tail -f' with this solution:

`sudo cat /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log | grep -v datab|perl -pe 's/(\d+)/localtime($1)/e'`

Using this on linux, but should work on WSL/cygwin.

Comment: Why can't you swap the `cat` for `tail -f`? and if not then the cat is redundant and you should just let grep open the file